# Streaming Hololens Camera into Unity Video Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I'm developping a Universal Windows Application to stream Hololens Camera and interact with it. Can you help ?

**1st attack angle :** Creating a Unity project and build in UWP.

I have succefully create the SharingServer from Holotoolkit-Unity and i can send custom message to the hololens from my unity app. But impossible to get video stream from device portal into a classic Unity video player

using https://[username]:[password]@[HololensIP]/api/holographic/stream/live.mp4?holo=true&pv=true&mic=true&loopback=true

returning `WindowsVideoMedia error 0x80072f8f while reading [url]`

I suppose the problem is comming from the video type (without duration) but it's .mp4 H264 witch should be accepted.

In front of that impossible wall, i start over into Visual Studio making directly a UWP.

**2nd attack angle** : UWP straight from VS2017

There i can use **WindowsDeviceProtalWrapper** to get the stream and display it into a MediaElement.

But right now impossible to import SharingClient.dll into VS.

So i can't send data to my hololens with my UWP.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I've been poking around with doing something similar to this as well [this sample project](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloLensCompanionKit/tree/master/MixedRemoteViewCompositor) but I haven't gotten it to work. One thing I *have* noticed is that I'll get *no response* (including the device portal!) unless I'm on an exact network subdomain (while treating the subnet mask as if it was 255.255.255.0 instead of whatever it really is).

Comment: If you are working with Unity3D, you may try a plugin called "FM Exhibition Tool Pack". It's cross-platform video+audio streaming solution.